# Angular 4 - want subscription to execute each time view is presented

Tags: angular

I am fairly new to Angular, and I am trying to create a scenario where a child component informs the parent component when a job is running and when it is finished, so that it won't have to run again if the child component is re-launched. To do this, I created an observable which from the child is invoked as follows:

```
 if (res.status === 'RanToCompletion') {     //if job completes
    this.entitiesLoadStatus.isEntitiesLoadInProgress = false;
    this.entitiesLoadStatus.isEntitiesLoadComplete = true;
    this.entitiesLoadStatus.lastRunDay = this.todaysDate.getDate();                  
    this.legalEntitiesService.emitEntityLoadStatus(this.entitiesLoadStatus);
```

In the parent, I have the following in OnInit():

```
this.legalEntitiesService.entitiesLoadStatusObservable.subscribe(data => {
        this.entitiesLoadStatus.isEntitiesLoadInProgress = data.isEntitiesLoadInProgress;
        this.entitiesLoadStatus.isEntitiesLoadComplete = data.isEntitiesLoadComplete;
        this.entitiesLoadStatus.lastRunDay = data.lastRunDay;
    });
```

The parent, in turn, returns this information to the child, which informs it whether or not to run the job.  My problem is that the subscription needs to run **each time the parent view is presented**, but if I simply close the child component the parent view is re-presented, but OnInit does not fire again.  How can I get the subscription to run each time the view is presented?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4hfkt

The work shouldn't be done inside the components/getting pushed from one component to another, instead that work should be lifted into a service. The changes to the view should be be a result of the data flowing down from the service.

To achieve this, the data for the child component needs to be held in a central, persistent state. Angular has "services" for this purpose.

The view doesn't manage the data of the child components, it just handles passing the data from the persistent "service" layer, down to the presentational layer.

NgRx is a great way to manage state.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this solves the problem of executing a subscription each time a view is presented.  Can you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: Updated my answer and the project I linked. You need to use a persistent state to handle holding that data. See link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4hfkt